# Using chain package from tikz in TeXLive 2015 as standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive, standalone, tikz-chains

I'm trying to include a simple example of `chain` usage from `tikz` into my document compiled with `TeXLive`.

The problem is, when I try to create a chain, compilation error occurs:

```
Package standalone Warning: Graphic '../tikz/5_40_video_tree.pdf' could not be 
build.
Shell escape activated? on input line 393.

(./5_main/../tikz/5_40_video_tree.tex

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/start chain', to which yo
u passed '1 going right', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled i
t.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 ...chain=1 going right,node distance=-0.15mm]

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.12 ...chain=1 going right,node distance=-0.15mm]

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on index.log.
```

Included document is a cut version of a [Turing machine](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/turing-machine/) example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every path}=[very thick]

\begin{scope}[start chain=1 going right,node distance=-0.15mm]
    \node [on chain=1,draw=none] {$\ldots$};
    \node [on chain=1] {};
    \node [on chain=1] (input) {b};
    \node [on chain=1] {b};
    \node [on chain=1] {a};
    \node [on chain=1] {a};
    \node [on chain=1] {a};
    \node [on chain=1] {a};
    \node [on chain=1] {};
    \node [on chain=1,draw=none] {$\ldots$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I include it via

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{../tikz/5_40_video_tree}
\end{figure}
```

TikZ and TeXLive are actually working: I've already included another TikZ documents this way, they use plotting and trees.
Also the example image can be compiled separately into PDF, so the problem is how to include it into my document without separate compiling.

Comment: Are you sure `mode=buildnew` does not force that behavior?

Comment: Try using `mode=buildmissing`.

Comment: Have you loaded the `chains` library in your main document? We do not currently have the code you are compiling to produce the error, so we can only guess. Have you enabled shell escape?

Comment: @cfr thanks! I've forgotten to use the `chains` TikZ library in my main document. Thought, it's enough to use it in the included one. Can you post the answer for me in order to mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code in the included document to work, it is necessary to do one of two things.

Either make sure that all required packages and libraries are loaded in the main document's preamble.

Or look at the `subpreambles` option of `standalone`. If you use this, `standalone` will try to figure out what needs to be included.

Personally, I always use the first approach as it is clearer what I'm doing and one thing fewer to go wrong!